# Renumbering a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a big problem in SQL Server. In one of my tables, I have an auto number column. When some row is deleted, numbering in this column gets messy. I want to renumber it using a stored procedure. How can I do this?

Comment: That's not really the way Identity columns are mean to be used, I hope you aren't using that key as a link to other tables. But you might be able to use DBCC CHECKIDENT.

Answer (score 2):

An `identity` column uniquely identifies each row in a table. That is its purpose. Generally these are also primary keys in the table concerned. They are used for foreign key references.

**You do not want to change the values after they have been created.** In other words, you want an identifier for each row that is consistent across the database and consistent across time. You don't want "27" to mean one thing today and a different thing next month.

If you want some sort of sequential number with no gaps, then use `row_number()` when you query the table. This will "fill in" the gaps, although the particular number assigned to a given row can vary over time.